# Can we use wildcard to have multiple paths while mentioning "AuthorizedKeysFile" in sshd_config?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, sshd

I want to have one public per one authorized key file.

Example:

In the dir %h/.ssh/

- For person A, separate file A_authorized_key containing public key for A
- For person B, separate file B_authorized_key containing public key for B

ls %h/.ssh/ will give:

- A_authorized_key
- B_authorized_key

I know we can write both public keys in `authorized_keys` file, and it will work like a charm, but due to some reason I want it to be in separate files.

So can we write `AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/*` ?

Can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can not use wildcards in the `AuthorizedKeysFile`. You can use multiple files, but not wildcards.

> `AuthorizedKeysFile`
>
> **Specifies the file** that contains the public keys used for user authentication. ...

But you can create a script, that will pick all these keys and give them to the `ssh`, which will run it as `AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand` and `AuthorizedKeysCommandUser`:

```
AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand /path/to/script
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
```

and the script can look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="~${1}/.ssh/*"
cat `eval echo $DIR
```

but note that your wildcard matches also the private keys of the user and it is never a good idea when you touch these keys.